# Allowing/Restricting XML Attributes based other Attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to create an XML schema with the following behavior? I have an XML file that looks like the following. I'd like to either expose or restrict attributes of Object based on the value of Type. For example, if Type="Bike" I might want to expose attributes related only to Bike (i.e. Pedals, Frame, etc). If the Type="Car", I might want to expose attributes that are only relevant to Car (i.e. Make, Model, Miles, etc).

```
<Objects>
  <Object Type="Bike" Pedals="XXX" Frame="XXX" />
  <Object Type="Car" Make="XXX" Model="XXX" Miles="XXX" />
</Objects>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that this is beyond what you can do with xsd. Besides, it makes querying a nightmare. The preferred approach (if it is possible) is to use:

```
<vehicles>
  <bike pedals="XXX" frame="XXX" />
  <car make="XXX" model="XXX" miles="XXX" />
</vehicles>
```

Where `car` and `bike` presumably have a common root `vehicle` in the xsd, but their own specific properties (on top of the inherited ones).

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any technical resons why this wouldn't be possible - this is absolutely the correct approach and has even been specifically addressed by the W3C though I'm struggling to find the document.

Comment: by "if it is possible", I meant "for your scenario" ;-p

Answer (score 2):

I think you are cramming too many things into attributes. Things like Pedals and Frame should probably be elements.

Comment: Old thread but, why? They are simple values why should the be elements instead of attributes?

Comment: @Josh - http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp <- I agree with those bullet points.

Comment: Sure, I can see that. But also the attribute takes up less bytes than the element start+body+end tags. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Josh - If you're concerned about size, I think you might be using the wrong tool for the job. The same argument can be made that `Pedals` takes too many bytes and if you simply named that field `P` you could save a lot of storage. Does that sound like a good idea? That may seem like reductio ad absurdum but really, it would save a lot of bytes. How about this: compress the XML. Then you can have whatever schema your team likes and still save a lot of space.

Comment: I'm not concerned about size, just mentioning it.  We're in agreement here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970146/allowing-restricting-xml-attributes-based-other-attributes/970169#970169) that what you're trying to do is outside of the capabilities of W3C XML-Schema. I'd also agree that you're data model is just a bit overloaded/ambiguous to be useful. However, if you have no choice in the matter then perhaps either [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) or [Relax-NG](http://www.relaxng.org/) could provide a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to use `xsi:type` instead of `Type` for XSD polymorphism (and in the schema, derive the types from a common type):

```
<Objects>
  <Object xsi:type="Bike" Pedals="XXX" Frame="XXX" />
  <Object xsi:type="Car" Make="XXX" Model="XXX" Miles="XXX" />
</Objects>
```

For details, see the [XML Schema Part 0: Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/). It has an [example schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#address.xsd) for this, in which **USAddress** and **UKAddress** types are derived from **Address**.  Further down is an [example instance](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#UseDerivInInstDocs) using `xsi:type`.